# CakePHP: How can I invalidate form fields when hasMany association is used?

Tags: validation, cakephp

I need to validate data in code as some validation rules depend on more than one field.

My models are `Person`, `Address` & `Hobby`. Associations look like this:

```
Person 
    hasOne Address
    hasMany Hobby

Address
    belongsTo Person

Hobby
    belongsTo Person
```

Now when any field of the `Person` model is not correct or any `Address` field is not correct I can simply write the following code in my controller to inform user he/she needs to correct given field:

```
// this works fine!
$this->Person->invalidate('person_model_field_name', __('Help text'));
$this->Person->Address->invalidate('address_model_field_name', __('Help text'));
```

**Now, how can I invalidate any of the `Hobby` model fields in a similar way?**

I tried really hard last night and all my attempts failed. I cannot believe there is no way to do this in CakePHP v. 2.4.3 (after all this is not one of the first releases, right?).

```
// doesn't work
$this->Person->Hobby->invalidate('hobby_model_field_name', __('Help text'));
// doesn't work neither
$this->Person->Hobby->invalidate('Hobby.0.hobby_model_field_name', __('Help text'));
// tried to work directly on validationErrors array but also failed
```

I've also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261277/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-display-validation-errors-for-hasmany-associations-i) but I am still lost. :-(

**UPDATE**

To shed some light here is an example why I need this:

For instance: when `Person.is_student` field is `true` user needs to fill in `Person.studies_year` field; otherwise he/she needs to fill in `Person.diploma_date` field. So in `Person` model validation rules for both `studies_year` and `diploma_date` I need to use `allowEmpty` rule. Similar case with Hobby model.

Comment: It sounds to me like that you should be considering using custom validation rules.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#custom-validation-rules

Comment: Possibly. However my validation rules depend not only on models data, they also depend on process workflow. That's why I'd prefer to invalidate some field manually.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use

```
$this->Person->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true));
```

if the validation fails, you can read all the validation messages in:

```
$this->Person->validationErrors;
```

and you define all the validation rules and messages **in your model**

Comment: Well, that's what I do. But after my model is saved (`SaveAll` method) I need to check additional conditions - I've just updated  my question with some background info on this issue. Anyway, what I need is to **write** to the `$this->Person->validationErrors` or indicate to the user in any other way that certain field value is not correct. Also, I allow model data to be saved as there are many fields to fill-in and I do not want the user to lose any of his edits even when some fields are not correct.

Comment: I have a similar situation in my project and I use:
$this->Person->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true, 'validation' => true)); 

and when I try to save hasMany, or any other association I get error message in $this->Person->validationErrors;

Comment: That's OK, it works for me too. :-) But on top of that I want to indicate that for instance field `Hobby.0.kind` is invalid because `Person.age` is below some limit.

Comment: oh. Now I get it. I would still try to write custom validation rules :D I think it's much simpler than this.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Unfortunatelly some of my validation rules depend on data not stored in any of my models but rather on a defined workflow. I guess I could "glue" somehow my custom validation rule but I'd rather not do that as it smells bad. ;-) I just need a way to invalidate the field I want.